# How to fix "sudo: ./install.sh: command not found" error when configuring "seed 4-Channel 16-Bit ADC for Raspberry Pi (ADS1115)"?

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi3, adc

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 B with Raspbian Stretch installed and trying to install the ADC Hat titled as per the tutorial http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/4-Channel_16-Bit_ADC_for_Raspberry_Pi-ADS1115/. But I keep getting stuck at when running the command "sudo ./install.sh -u adc_ads1115 ". I get the error as:

sudo: ./install.sh: command not found

I've enabled the I2C of my Raspberry Pi as well.

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to check out this board, too: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JamesBrown Thank you very much for the guidance, I will check this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions you are following are out of date. The project's README suggests [this page](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/pi-hats/tree/master/ADC-HAT#installation) whose instructions additionally read:

```
# open tools directory
cd tools

# Install driver
sudo ./install.sh -u adc_ads1115

# sync all setting
sync
```

`install.sh` is in `pi-hats/tools/install.sh`, so you have to cd to `pi-hats/tools` instead of just the `pi-hats` base directory.

Comment: Yes... "install.sh" was in the "pi-hats/tools" :o  this works for me. :D

i@raspberrypi:~/pi-hats/tools $ sudo ./install.sh -l
adc_ads1115   : installed
rtc_ds1307    : not installed
rtc_ds3231    : not installed

Thank you very much for the support with the explanation :) This helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The file is most likely missing permissions to execute. To add the required permissions, issue a chmod command: `chmod a+x install.sh` which means "add +x(permission to execute) for all users (a) )

Comment: Thank you for the help and I tried that. But it doesn't work for me :(. The error is
"chmod: cannot access 'install.sh' : No such file or directory"

Comment: Worked for me :D